# i'm getting local datetime from database using json

Tags: java, json, ajax, spring-mvc, json-serialization

I'm getting data from database in json format. local datetime is problem

> {"dayOfMonth":4,"dayOfWeek":1,"era":1,"year":2017,"dayOfYear":247,"chronology":{"zone":{"fixed":true,"id":"UTC"}},"weekOfWeekyear":36,"millisOfSecond":0,"secondOfMinute":0,"centuryOfEra":20,"yearOfEra":2017,"yearOfCentury":17,"weekyear":2017,"monthOfYear":9,"millisOfDay":0,"minuteOfHour":0,"hourOfDay":0,"fields":[{"lenient":false,"maximumValue":292278993,"minimumValue":-292275054,"rangeDurationField":null,"leapDurationField":{"precise":true,"unitMillis":86400000,"name":"days","type":{"name":"days"},"supported":true},"durationField":{"precise":false,"unitMillis":31556952000,"name":"years","type":{"name":"years"},"supported":true},"name":"year","type":{"rangeDurationType":null,"durationType":{"name":"years"},"name":"year"},"supported":true},{"lenient":false,"maximumValue":12,"minimumValue":1,"rangeDurationField":{"precise":false,"unitMillis":31556952000,"name":"years","type":{"name":"years"},"supported":true},"leapDurationField":{"precise":true,"unitMillis":86400000,"name":"days","type":{"name":"days"},"supported":true},"durationField":{"precise":false,"unitMillis":2629746000,"name":"months","type":{"name":"months"},"supported":true},"name":"monthOfYear","type":{"rangeDurationType":{"name":"years"},"durationType":{"name":"months"},"name":"monthOfYear"},"supported":true},{"maximumValue":31,"minimumValue":1,"rangeDurationField":{"precise":false,"unitMillis":2629746000,"name":"months","type":{"name":"months"},"supported":true},"lenient":false,"durationField":{"precise":true,"unitMillis":86400000,"name":"days","type":{"name":"days"},"supported":true},"unitMillis":86400000,"name":"dayOfMonth","type":{"rangeDurationType":{"name":"months"},"durationType":{"name":"days"},"name":"dayOfMonth"},"supported":true,"leapDurationField":null},{"range":86400000,"maximumValue":86399999,"rangeDurationField":{"precise":true,"unitMillis":86400000,"name":"days","type":{"name":"days"},"supported":true},"lenient":false,"durationField":{"name":"millis","type":{"name":"millis"},"supported":true,"precise":true,"unitMillis":1},"minimumValue":0,"unitMillis":1,"name":"millisOfDay","type":{"rangeDurationType":{"name":"days"},"durationType":{"name":"millis"},"name":"millisOfDay"},"supported":true,"leapDurationField":null}],"fieldTypes":[{"rangeDurationType":null,"durationType":{"name":"years"},"name":"year"},{"rangeDurationType":{"name":"years"},"durationType":{"name":"months"},"name":"monthOfYear"},{"rangeDurationType":{"name":"months"},"durationType":{"name":"days"},"name":"dayOfMonth"},{"rangeDurationType":{"name":"days"},"durationType":{"name":"millis"},"name":"millisOfDay"}],"values":[2017,9,4,0]}},{"reg_id":86,"name":"we","mobilenumber":8099677558,"email":"aa@gmail.com","register_mode":"Offline
>   Paid","rating":0,"password":"fsdfsf","promo_mode":null,"repair_mode":null,"modified_by":null,"created_by":null},{"reg_id":87,"name":"adfdsfdsf","mobilenumber":5444445555,"email":"sadfsdafds@gmial.com","register_mode":"Online","rating":0,"password":null,"promo_mode":"Notpromo","repair_mode":null,"modified_by":null,"created_by":null},

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/getUsers", method=RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=application/json")
        public ResponseEntity<List<RegistrationAmc>> getregistrationusers() {


              HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                List<RegistrationAmc> list = frntService.getregistrationusers();    
               for(RegistrationAmc r:list){

                        LocalDateTime localDate = new LocalDateTime();
                        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/dd/MM");
                        String formattedDate = formatter.print(localDate);
                        System.out.println("ggggg"+formattedDate);
                        System.out.println("ssssssssssssss....."+r);

               }


              if (list == null) {
               return new ResponseEntity<List<RegistrationAmc>>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
              }
              headers.add("Number Of Records Found", String.valueOf(list.size()));
              return new ResponseEntity<List<RegistrationAmc>>(list, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
             }
```

Comment: Which property? How do you store json? Please clarify your question and provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'm guessing the spring JSON serialization is done internally using Jackson? You need to write a custom serializer, and use it with annotations.

Comment: Also DateTimeFormatter from the Java 8 datetime API you are using is thread-safe, so it's best you have that formatter in a `static final` somewhere, and don't create it every time. certainly not in the loop as it is now.